# Web page showing index list

Tags: apache-2.2, web-hosting, indexes

I am using Apache 2.2.22 for web hosting and I had created a directory tree like **C:/server/www/apacheserver.dev/public_html** and put everything (my web page file) inside the **public_html**, but inside the public_html I still have sub directory file and inside the sub directory file I still have another sub directory file. So my web page directory looked something like **C:/server/www/apacheserver.dev/public_html/sub-directory/another-sub-dir** and the whole coding is inside the **another-sub-dir**.

So every time I tried to access into my main page by typing the url, the web page will show index of and there only have one list of file, which is my **sub-directory** file. If I click the file then I will be redirected to another index list and it is the **Index of/sub-directory**. There got two types of list. **Parent Directory** and **another-sub-dir** and I have no idea where is that **Parent Directory** came from, because there is no such file inside my directory. But that isn't really the matter.

So, to get access into the main log in of the web page (**Index.php**), I have to click each of the file. I saw a lot of people post the same question and the only answer that given is add **DirectoryIndex index.html index.php** and this line already exist inside my **httpd.conf**. It means that this solution isn't helping me.

Is there anybody who could tell me on how to redirect user to the main page (index.php) without going through the selecting files?

Answer (score 0):

Apache is case sensitive, unless you made a typo in the question, your `Index.php` file should be renamed to `index.php`.

Second, it sounds like you need to set the [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive to the correct base directory you want to use for your web content as well.

When no IndexDocument is found, by default Apache will generate a representation of the directory structure with [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) where the *"Parent Directory"* is one level up the directory tree.

Comment: I checked it many times and the `index.php` is correct. Maybe you're right. I also think that it might be the `DocumentRoot`. I need to check it again and will update the result here.

Comment: Hello, it seems like my `DocumentRoot` is correct. This is the site where I refer to for manual installation of Apache and PHP. http://www.bogotobogo.com/php/apache_php_mysql.php  . Any clue?

Answer (score -1):

Are the php package already installed on your server?

You can see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Comment: If I haven't install it yet I couldn't go this far.